# AppLocker failing for SHA-256 hash signatures on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, applocker

I just found that on my Windows 7 (x64, latest patches applied) I am unable to have it generate any rules based on a signer, if the file which I am trying to use to generate has *only* a SHA-256 signature (i.e. isn't dual-signed or signed with SHA-1 only).

I'm not sure if there is also a correlation to the hash type used by the CA to sign the certificate used for signing.

Is this an artificial limitation in Windows 7 or am I doing something wrong? How can I convince AppLocker to take these files without having to resort to file hash based rules or path based rules?

After all Microsoft calls Windows 7 still *supported* **and** they're pushing everyone to move to SHA-256-based signatures. So it'd seem odd had AppLocker been ignored in all of this.